# Replacement Freehub cassette

Tags: gears, cassette, freehub

I'm planning on changing my cassette to 11-32.
Im running a Shimano 12-28 8 speed at the moment.

I have no markings on my old cassette and I'm a little confused at all the letters and numbers they use.

Obviously they mean nothing to me as I have no markings to compare.

Can I safely assume If I buy a Shimano 8 speed cassette it will fit my freehub?

Comment: Yes, going from Shimano 8 speed to a different ratio Shimano 8 speed should give you no issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, yes, all Shimano and Shimano-compatible (SRAM, Sunrace, etc) 8-speed cassettes are interchangeable in terms of their overall length and fit onto the freehub body. However, hubs from the early years of cassettes might be either Uniglide or have the original Hyperglide freehub design that precluded use of an 11t cog. Much more info [here.](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/k7.html)

Shimano comes up with different schemes for how the ramping, shift gates, and other design aspects of their cassettes are supposed to work together. The codes stamped on their cogs deal with what scheme that cog belongs to and what gear position it's supposed to be in it.